# memcached not working in docker-compose

Tags: php, docker-compose, memcached

I have problem with memcached in docker-compose. This is docker-compose.yml:

```
nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
        - 127.0.0.2:8000:80
    volumes:
        - ./htdocs:/htdocs
        - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
    links:
        - php
php:
    container_name: php
    build: ./php
    volumes:
        - ./htdocs:/htdocs
        - ./php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini  
    links:
        - mysql
        - memcached
mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
        - 127.0.0.2:8001:3306
    volumes:
        - ./my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
        - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=db
        - MYSQL_USER=root
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
memcached:
    container_name: memcached
    image: memcached:latest
    ports:
        - "11211:11211"
```

and this is my php code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

$memcached = new Memcached; 

$memcached->addServer('0.0.0.0', 11211);

echo '<pre>'; print_r($memcached->getServerList()); echo '</pre>';

if($memcached->getStats() === false) {
    echo 'returned false';
} else {
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($memcached->getStats()); echo '</pre>';
}
```

and result is:

```
Array
(
     [0] => Array
        (
            [host] => 0.0.0.0
            [port] => 11211
            [type] => TCP
        )
)

returned false
```

Why memcached cant see server? (getStats returned nothing) Command "docker ps" return list where it`s running docker memcached:lastest as port "0.0.0.0:11211->11211/tcp". Sorry  for my english.

Comment: for php memcached should be running at host "memcached", port 11211.

Comment: $memcached->addServer('memcached', 11211) and its working :) Thanks :)

Comment: You should be using this for the rest of the linked containers as well. In PHP when connecting to mysql it's much better to use the linked name than some IP.

Answer (score 14):

Just replace host `0.0.0.0` to `memcached`

Host `memcached` link to IP of memcached container.